# How to lubricate a plain bearing

Tags: lubrication, bushing

I am trying to repair a squealing heating blower motor.
The shaft doesn't have feel-able tilt play in the bushings, so I suspect the bushing isn't yet worn out. The shaft looks scratched, but I barely feel something with a fingernail. Previous attempts at just dropping in some oil didn't last long.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update:**

I tried to soak the bearings in oil, by vacuum-sealing them. For now the squealing is gone.
[image]

Comment: Put oil in the bag before , then evacuate . The vacuum will draw out air then the oil bath will be drawn into the porosity as vacuum is released.

Comment: @blacksmith37 I did that, in a sense. I sealed the lower opening of the bearings with duct tape, filled the resulting "cup" with oil, placed the "shells" in the bag, and evacuated the bag..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is an oilight bush / bearing then I would soak it in oil - overnight if you can arrange it and a light oil so it goes in easily even heat it a little.

Comment: Heat will expand air and it will come out making room for oil to fill voids . Vacuum works well too, if available.

Answer (score 2):

The first picture looks like a needle -rolling element - bearing , not a bushing. Can't tell from picture but if it is silver , not red or yellow ,it is a needle ( steel). If a needle has spun on the shaft ,your motor is dead. A new bearing would be relatively costly and may also spin on the shaft , depending on wear. If a plain bronze bushing ,put oil on it.

Comment: It is a plain bearing, bronze or some sinter-material